# No output for JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm developing a JSP application without any framework. I started using Netbeans with the Glassfish server, but had no output. Then moved to the tomcat and the same problem exist.

Even for wrong file path the browser shows blank page and no error [ex: http://localhost:8080/invalid]

ANd code like this also dont have any output in Tomcat or Glassfish

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
int i=0;
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
 System.out.print(i + "<br/>");
%>
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: I can view http://localhost:8080/manager without any problem though ! Glassfish can also render HTML but no texts inside JSP tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output System.out.println is outputting is to the console/logs, not to the web page. System.out refers to the overall system's standard out, that would be bound to the console. What you want to do is out.println (No System.) .

Answer (score 0):

The output System.out.println is outputting is to the console of the server, you can able to see the message in the server console but  not to the web page.

Please change your as shown below

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
 <%
  int i=0;
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  out.print(i + "<br//>");
%>
```

Here:
out -> refers the JspWriter object.

**Out:** We can out variable directly in the JSP scriplet without we declaring it. 
**out --JSPWriter**
**JSPWriter** is a class which is available in javax.servlet.jsp package.

In servlet we are used printWriter to send the output to the client. In JSP we use JSPWriter.

***What is the difference between PrintWriter and JSPWriter?**

Every JSPWriter is associated with 8KB of internal Buffer. Where as PrintWriter doesn’t associated with any Buffer.
Ex: We can use both print and write() is an out variable.

```
<%
 int a = 10;
 int b = 20;
 out.print(“A value is:”+a);
 out.write(“B value is:”+b);
%>
```